# Display selected element block and other element none using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have one drop down in html and it has 3 options,when i select any of them the form div gets
displayed block ,but if i select other the previous one not gets displayed none then how should i do this? Keeping one block and others none

```
<select id="walker" name="walker">
<option value="">Select Walker</option>
<option value="1">walker1</option><option value="2">walker2</option><option value="3">walker3</option></select>

<div id="form_div">
<div id="walker1" style="display:none;"></div>  
<div id="walker2" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="walker3" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>

      $("#walker").change(function(){
               var numwalker= parseInt($("select#walker option:selected").val()); 

               $('#walker'+numwalker).css('display','block');

             })
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be answered in one letter.

Comment: i have used "walker1" instead of "walker-1" so now its done using show and hide method

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```
$('#walker'+numwalker).show().siblings().hide();
```

[**See udpated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WXf3q/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Give all the `#walker` a common class, and hide all of them, *before* you show the one selected.

```
<select id="walker" name="walker">
<option value="">Select Walker</option>
<option value="1">walker1</option><option value="2">walker2</option><option value="3">walker3</option></select>

<div id="form_div">
<div class="walkers" id="walker1" style="display:none;"></div> 
<div class="walkers" id="walker2" style="display:none;"></div>
<div class="walkers" id="walker3" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>

$("#walker").change(function(){
               var numwalker= parseInt($("select#walker option:selected").val()); 
               $('.walkers').hide();  // <-- Hide all of them
               $('#walker'+numwalker).show()  // You can use .show() instead of altering the css.

             })
```

Also, a maybe more elegant way of solving it, would be to utilize the ["Starts With Selector"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) instead of giving them a common class; as such:

```
$('div[id^="walker"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to hide all the children() of `#form_div`;

```
$("#form_div").children().hide();
$('#walker-'+numwalker).show();
```

You also missed out the `-` in your selector id;

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonnathan/HVB3L/) for demo.